# Find function $f(x)$, such that $f(x+ \frac{1}{x}) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

The question is,

> Find function $f(x)$, if $f(x+ \frac{1}{x}) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

What does this mean?

Do I have to find $x$ in $x+ \frac{1}{x} = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$?
In this case (not counting solutions in the complex plane), $x = 1; f(x) = 2$.

Or replace all $x$'s in $x+ \frac{1}{x}$, so that it would equal $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$?
In that case, $f(x) = x^2$

Or some other option?

Comment: $f(x) = x^2 - 2$

Comment: You are supposed to find all functions $f$ that have the property that for every non-zero $x$, $f\left(x+\frac1x\right)$ is equal to $x^2+\frac1{x^2}$. Start with $x$, form the sum $x+\frac1x$, and apply the function $f$ to that sum; the result is supposed to be $x^2+\frac1{x^2}$, no matter what $x$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that

$$\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2=x^2+\frac1{x^2}+2$$

so in fact

$$f(x):=x^2-2\;\;\;\text{gives}\;\;\;f\left(x+\frac1x\right)=\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2-2=x^2+\frac1{x^2}$$

Comment: Well, that gives an answer to the equation, but not much in terms of an explanation. Thanks regardless.

Comment: " not much in terms of an explanation"?? What else do you want? It is a matter of *recognizing* a rather well known pattern of the binomial expression from high school and make the easy deduction.

Comment: *A technical point.* I also think that this is the intended solution. But technically there are uncountably many solutions $f :\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ of the given functional equation, since the range of $x \mapsto x + \frac{1}{x}$ is $(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty)$, which does not cover the entire $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Perhaps , so what? The question asked "find function...", not **"all the functions..."** . This is *a* function, probably the simplest one. No domain or range are given so I figured the question only cared about an algebraic rule, which turned to be very simple.

Comment: Sorry if my comment made you uncomfortable, I just wanted to point out that the problem is probably not well-designed to give many solutions.

Comment: @SangchulLee No apologies needed at all, but thank you anyway: I didn't feel uncomfortable at all, and I think you're right about the kind of problem.

Comment: @Tom: For _large_ $x$ we have that the argument $x+\frac1x$ is close to $x$, and the desired result is close to $x^2$, so the asymptotic growth rate of $f$ for $x\to\infty$ must be as $x\mapsto x^2$. It is therefore natural to try to see how far $f(y)=y^2$ itself is from satisfying the equation, with the hope that any discrepancy might be easier to handle than the original equation -- which is what DonAntonio does here.

Comment: @Torn what Don probably means is that if you've been given this particular question only, then it probably means you're not expected to know how to solve such problems in general but you're expected to be so familiar with that formula that you're able to solve it by recognition.